# What is 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef' with Tensorflow version 2.0.0?

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, object-detection

I am using the following function in part of object detection application I am working on

```
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
  od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
  with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')
```

When I run this code I get the following error :

---

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-6-d55b98fd5a78> in <module>
      1 detection_graph = tf.Graph()
      2 with detection_graph.as_default():
----> 3   od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
      4   with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_FROZEN_GRAPH, 'rb') as fid:
      5     serialized_graph = fid.read()

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphDef'
```

I am using TensorFlow 2.0.0. Is this a version mismatch related?

This code is from the following [link](https://pythonprogramming.net/introduction-use-tensorflow-object-detection-api-tutorial/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you have properly installed the libraries as given in link,

```
https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/installation.md
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is a version mismatch issue, you should not blindly assume that every library supports TensorFlow 2.0, which was only recently released.

If a library does not advertise explicit support for TensorFlow 2.0, then you should just use it with TensorFlow 1.x